# Weird querySelector interaction (not clicking)

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Basically, I have this piece of code:

```
    if (this.variantId || theme.config.mqlSmall) {
      this.addEventListener('click', this.onHoverHandler.bind(this));
      this.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("hello")
      });
    }
```

That should triggers when a color selector get's clicked. It is adding the event listener into my color selector, but it's not triggering :S I'm a little confused about this, never happened to me

[image: This is the structure of my color swatch (this)]

[image: Also this is when my event is loaded]

I want it to trigger the function when I click on it

Comment: in your code, what is `this` and `this.onHoverHandler`?

Comment: have you debugged it?

Comment: What are the other listeners doing? Is any of them stopping propagation?

Comment: this is <color-swatch> the custom component, and no, those other event listeners are related to fb pixel. this.onHoverHandler() is the function i want to run

Comment: I even tried removing all the other listeners and trying to click but no result

Comment: After going through your code looks like you want to trigger a function on click of an anchor tag.

This can be done in a much simpler way.